# Why is my Rails.root nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to reference Rails.root in my application.rb but it is nil, why is that?

Comment: yes, it loads fine, but when it returns null, even in rails console.

Comment: @Blankman: this is a question that you could accept.

Answer (score 12):

I can explain why, but I can't give you a workaround.

`Rails.root` is defined in [rails/railties/lib/rails.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails.rb)

```
def root
  application && application.config.root
end
```

In `application.rb`, the instance of `application` is not yet created, because the `Application` class is being defined... The application is only initialized after, in `environment.rb`:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Testapp::Application.initialize!
```

**EDIT**

The workaround is right before our eyes:

```
my_rails_root = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Rails 3.x? If not, you should be using `RAILS_ROOT` rather than `Rails.root`.

Comment: Even `RAILS_ROOT` is `nil` in `application.rb`

Comment: The reason is described by Thomas Guillory. It is not yet called.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to use it before the module and class declaration. Try using it inside and see if that makes a difference e.g.

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    puts Rails.root

  end
end
```