# How do I get the root directory of a Rails app in a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is it possible to know the Rails file system root of an application in the code of a gem included in an app?

This is a sample of the gem source:

```
module MyGem
  def self.included(base)
    puts Rails.root # return nil
  end
end

ActionController::Base.send :include, MyGem
```

Thank's and sorry for my poor english

Comment: Chat speak is discouraged here. If you're going to add "thanks" to your posts (which you shouldn't do anyways), type "thanks", not "thx".

Comment: I haven't done much with ruby gems, but I am wondering will ```root_path``` not work?

Comment: The file system root directory? or the URL root_path?

Comment: Sorry, the file system root directory!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution that I found to fix a similar problem to this is to include my module using the railtie initializers.

So, in your /lib/mygem/railtie.rb

```
module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "Include your code in the controller" do
      ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
        include MyGem
      end
    end
end
```

With this code, your module will be included after the ActionController is loaded and you will be able to use Rails.root

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Of course:

```
Rails.root
```

Just because you're writing a gem doesn't mean you can't access the global namespace.  The only concern would be if your Gem uses that access before the Rails module is set up during initialization.  If you find that's the problem, post the code you're using, where it is, and we'll be glad to help debug the issue.

Comment: Rails.root returns nil in that case.

Comment: That should not happen.  More context perhaps - is the sample you added to the question running in a full Rails app, or are you testing it with RSpec or similar?  When in the initialization process are you calling #send :include ?

Comment: It's running in a full Rails app. The include is called when the gem gets included, the code is basically the same...

Comment: Try moving your `require 'my-gem'` call after your Application definition (in config/application.rb), and see what that gets you - the problem is where in the init process you're causing your code to run.

Comment: My gem is included in the Gemfile. How can I delay the inclusion?

Comment: `gem 'my-gem', :require => false` in your gemfile would do it.  Alternately, you can move your include call into a method, and call that during init, something like `MyGem.init`.

Comment: `Rails.root` will return `nil` if you are accessing it before the `application` instance is created. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9896665/736